# Ubuntu 18.04 bluetooth not working in lenovo laptop

Tags: drivers, 18.04, bluetooth

Bluetooth not working ubuntu 18.04 on lenovo laptop.

When I run `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; rfkill list; uname -r; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` . Below is what I get

```
Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [17aa:3802]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [17aa:0611]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:004b Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 174f:148d Syntek 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0e8d:2005 MediaTek Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5.3.0-26-generic
[    0.140199] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.176078] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[   23.789800] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[   27.790136] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   27.790156] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   27.790159] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   27.790161] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   27.790164] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   50.515945] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   50.515946] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   50.515958] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  364.510611] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[  364.511611] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[  364.527612] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[  364.528623] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[  364.545643] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd failed with error -2
[  364.545649] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd not found
[  364.674287] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  364.674299] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  364.674315] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: @Pilot6 seems complex. I will try that

Comment: It is easy enough. Just get the `BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd` file.

Comment: @Pilot6 Indeed... Just need to find the correct file which I got from a simple google search. Working now as expected. Thank you.